# frozen food delivered on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, mail

If one ordered frozen food from an online store and it happened to be delivered at the person's front door on shabbat (unintended) would it be permissible to place the food in a freezer (with no light on of course to prevent monetary loss) even though it would not be used during shabbat or would the frozen food be considered mukzah (and should not be touched)?

Comment: As I understand, some opinions prohibit touching mail on Shabbat as it is considered *Nolad*. I don't know if that condition would be made lenient if one were to eat the food on Shabbat, itself. The other problem, possibly, of placing the food in the freezer might be *shevut* - preparing on Shabbat for the next day.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the need to place the food in the freezer as these type of deliveries usually come with dry ice which would keep the food cold in the box it is in. The dry ice that comes in these packages usually last at least 24 hours beyond the delivery.

Comment: I'm gonna agree with Gershon's question. At the same time I'll add that most deliveries you receive on your front door were already in that city at the onset of Shabbos which would mean there is no techum shabbos problem which means as long as the item itself is not actually muktzah (nailpolish, power tools etc), than you may handle it.

Comment: BTW muktza can be touched (do not make Hava's mistake) the prohibition is moving, If I remember correctly if you do it in an unusual way it might be permitted

Comment: @user6591 - uncooked inedible foods (e.g. frozen raw chicken) is probably  Muktza on Shabbat.

Comment: @Danny True point.